# Objective-C: NSURLConnection response?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsurlconnection

So I'm new to Obj-C and I'm trying to call a web service and receive it's response...

After implementing the example in the Apple docs for NSURLConnection, I'm outputting my results to NSLog. Check this out:

```
2011-04-30 01:30:24.831 Cocoa_Sandbox[18424:903] The data was: <>
2011-04-30 01:30:25.837 Cocoa_Sandbox[18424:903] Got the response: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x100104110>
2011-04-30 01:30:25.838 Cocoa_Sandbox[18424:903] Receieved the data: <3c3f786d 6c207665 7273696f 6e3d2231 2e30223f 3e3c7265 73706f6e 73653e3c 72657375 6c743e73 75636365 73733c2f 72657375 6c743e3c 2f726573 706f6e73 653e>
2011-04-30 01:30:25.838 Cocoa_Sandbox[18424:903] Connection finished loading.
```

As you can see, the data is `<>` and the received data output is `<3c3f786d 6c207665 7273696f 6e3d2231 2e30223f 3e3c7265 73706f6e 73653e3c 72657375 6c743e73 75636365 73733c2f 72657375 6c743e3c 2f726573 706f6e73 653e>`

My PHP service is just echoing some XML:

`echo '<?xml version="1.0"?><response><result>success</result></response>';`

Can someone give me a clue?

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re asking. Before receiving a response, your data is empty. After having received a response, you have data. What is your actual question?

Comment: I thought my question was pretty obvious... what in the world is `<3c3f786d 6c207665 7273696f 6e3d2231 2e30223f 3e3c7265 73706f6e 73653e3c 72657375 6c743e73 75636365 73733c2f 72657375 6c743e3c 2f726573 706f6e73 653e>`? And all I see in my breakpoint is the same value nested over and over.

Comment: That’s how an instance of `NSData` is logged — it’s the sequence of bytes that comprise your data.

Comment: Okay... so dow to I receive the data and do anything normal with it? I couldn't care less about the bytes... I want to use this XML that I'm being given back.

Comment: See @xoail’s answer. HTTP is a protocol that transfers bytes and that’s what you get from a HTTP URL connection. It’s up to you to convert them to what’s needed in your application. If you want to parse the XML response, you can use `-[XMLParser initWithData:]`, which expects an `NSData` instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The response format is in `NSData`, and someone can correct me if I am wrong, but that's what gets shown if printed with `NSLog`. You can convert it to an `NSString` like this and see if it helps:

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: It’s not really a cast — you’re creating an `NSString` instance based upon an `NSData` instance.

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted to know. Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0):

BTW--I recommend looking into RestKit or ASIHTTP for this stuff... it can save you a lot of work. (ASIHTTP is basically a browser without the graphical front-end)

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/
http://restkit.org/

RestKit is newer and looks cool, but I haven't personally tried it. I've used ASIHTTPRequest quite a bit and it's very good.

Comment: The ASIHTTP project has been closed down and thus there is no support. [Official statement](http://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D;)

Comment: well that's too bad.. although he lists lots of alternatives. maybe someone else will continue the project?